# How do I add a system-wide menu item to the Applications menu?

Tags: menu, application-development, appmenu

I have manually installed a software to `/opt` and I wanted to add it to the Applications menu.

Although Ubuntu makes it dead easy to add it to my user's menu, how do I add it system wide, so that all users will see the application in their menu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create the proper `.desktop` file and place it in `/usr/share/applications` which is the global place for applications.

It would like something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Sample Application Name
Comment=A sample application
Exec=/opt/application
Icon=application.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Application
```

`Name` will set the name that appears in the menu, and `Category` will place it in a certain category in the menu. `Exec` is the command to start the program, it uses full paths and can also take parameters. You can open the other .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications` with a text editor to get an idea.

For more info: [desktop-files](http://library.gnome.org/devel/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en)

Comment: you were a bit faster :)

Comment: This was also what I have tired but after a reboot the newly added entry is gone.

Comment: @Octavian Is the new `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` gone as well?

Comment: @ændrük: No, thats what makes it so funny.

Answer (score 2):

To add an entry of a program installed manually system wide you need to create a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`.

Desktop files have the following syntax:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.0 # Program version if applicable
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=nameof-application # as it appears in the desktop entry
GenericName=generic-name # as it is named for real
Comment=What the application does # textual explanation
Exec=/opt/programfolder/program  # path to the program
Icon=/opt/programfolder/icon # path to the custom icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
Categories=AudioVideo;Audio; Network; # Category for Menu-Entry
MimeType=video;audio;
```

Edit the file to your needs and save it as root as `nameof-application.desktop`. Full specification of desktop entries can be found at [Freedesktop.org](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)

Comment: +1 for the specs. it contains a list of [recognized desktop entry keys](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html)