# How do I run this file? It has a white icon with a grey cog on it

Tags: python, files, 20.04, programming

I am programming in Python on Ubuntu 20.04 and have just compiled my first program using 'PyInstaller'.

The program is compiled as a stand alone file with a white icon with a grey cog on it. I have double clicked it, clicked 'run' on the menu and even gone into the files properties and ticked 'Allow executing file as program' but none of these work and it doesn't run.
The file doesn't have a '.exe' or anything like that at the end of it.

How do I run this? Have I compiled it wrong?

Comment: Running by clicking in file manager is no longer supported. Try running from terminal: `./name_of_executable` if the executable is in the working directory, or full path name if you are in another folder.

Comment: Thank you. I did this and it works in terminal so thank you:) Is there no way of running it outside of terminal?

Comment: Include it in your user menu. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/28583/how-do-i-add-a-system-wide-menu-item-to-the-applications-menu. Use .local/share/applications if the item should only be available for your user.

Comment: I elaborated my comments into an answer. Please consider accepting it if it was helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your compiled program needs to be set as executable. In Files, you can use "Permissions" tab in the "Properties" dialog you obtain by right-clicking the file and selecting"Properties". Alternatively, set the executable with the command `chmod +x name_of_the_executable>` in the terminal.

You can run an executable from a terminal or from the run prompt that appears when you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Unless the executable is in a folder that is included in your search path (`echo $PATH` will show your search path), you need to provide the full pathname of the executable file. If the executable is in your current folder, then you can run it with `./name_of_executable`.

To run it from your application menu, [create a launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28583/how-do-i-add-a-system-wide-menu-item-to-the-applications-menu). A launcher is a text file with a .desktop extension that is formatted in a specific way. To have the launcher appear in the menu of any user, put the launcher in `/usr/share/applications`. To have the launcher appear in your user menu only, place it in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: Thank you again and sorry for not marking it right away, I had to go Skype with my family. Your answer was very helpful:) And was the right one! I did another bit of searching after getting your answer and found out if I go to the directory (through terminal) that the .py file is in and type this:    chmod a+x FILENAME.py       into terminal, I can than run it by clicking the file.   Your answer was still helpful though before and after I found this out...Thank you:)

Comment: Indeed, you are right - one can run a program by double -clicking it - I think that was not that obvious anymore in Ubuntu 19.10 and before, but they may have changed that again. I corrected my answer and added the requirement for setting the file executable - may help future readers.